# multiple conditionals in excel is there a better function to use

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a problem with my excel formula, the formula is supposed to basically be a bunch of if functions written out it looks like

```
If (h3< 1, H3+1),
If (h3>= 5 and H3<= 10, H3+2),
Else H3+3
```

I tried to put it into an excel formula based on what I saw online and some YouTube videos on if functions in excel but it's saying I added too many arguments. "Error: You've entered too many arguments for this function". Is there a better way to do this formula? Should I be using AND instead of multiple IF's? Does anyone have any advice or suggestions? Also any recommendations on how to improve with excel?

Here's my current formula:
'''

```
=IF(H3>10, H3+3,
IF(H3<=10, H3>=5, H3+2,
IF(H3<1, H3+1)))
```

'''

I expect for the formula to add either 1, 2, or 3 based on H3.

Comment: No need for the `H3<=10` since any number *not* `>10` is automatically `<=10`. You also have not indicated what the result should be if the last condition (`H3<1` turns out to be false

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: THANK YOU! I actually just deleted the statement H3<= 10 and I'm not getting the error message. I wanted the result for H3<1 to be H3+1. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many arguments in the second nested if statment
=IF(H3>10, H3+3,**IF(H3<=10, H3>=5, H3+2, IF(H3<1, H3+1)))**

If statements have 3 conditions
1) the logic statement
2) what to do if the logic statement is true
3) what to do if the logic statement is false

In your second in your second if statement you have 4 conditions - it looks like 2 logic statments H3<=10 AND H3>=5.  If you want to use both of those logic statements, you will need to add in AND()

```
=IF(H3>10, H3+3,IF(and(H3<=10, H3>=5), H3+2, IF(H3<1, H3+1)))
```

Additionally, in this scenario, you only have 2 conditions for your final IF statement. You need to add in a final value for when all logic statements are false.

```
=IF(H3>10, H3+3,IF(and(H3<=10, H3>=5), H3+2, IF(H3<1, H3+1, "ADD VALUE FOR WHEN FALSE")))
```

Also be careful if you have blank cells, you might not get the answer you're looking for if H3 is ever blank.